# Bluetooth troubles with AR3012 on Gentoo

Tags: drivers, gentoo, bluetooth, firmware

I'm using Linux 3.14.14-gentoo with `BT_ATH3K` enabled. I've downloaded the latest linux-firmware from Portage (20131230), and bluez-5.21-r1.

My Bluetooth device is an AR3012 according to `lsusb`:

```
Bus 003 Device 003: ID 0cf3:3004 Atheros Communications, Inc.
```

I'd give you my `lsusb -v`, but it chokes there for some reason. Here is the card's entry:

```
Bus 003 Device 003: ID 0cf3:3004 Atheros Communications, Inc. 
lsusb: gconv.c:74: __gconv: Assertion `outbuf != ((void *)0) && *outbuf != ((void *)0)' failed.
```

`lsusb` exits after that. Anyone know what's going on there?

Anyway, my Bluetooth device wasn't being detected after setting up all of the above. Relevant information:

```
[vinny@gentoo ~]$ sudo rfkill list
0: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
[vinny@gentoo ~]$ hcitool dev
Devices:
```

On bootup, I could tell that the ath3k drivers weren't loading properly.

Here's some Bluetooth output early on in dmesg:

```
[    0.228135] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.18
[    0.228163] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
[    0.228166] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
[    0.228169] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[    0.228175] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
[    3.018728] Bluetooth: RFCOMM TTY layer initialized
[    3.019511] Bluetooth: RFCOMM socket layer initialized
[    3.020285] Bluetooth: RFCOMM ver 1.11
[    3.021051] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[    3.021818] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
[    3.022581] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
[    3.023344] Bluetooth: HIDP (Human Interface Emulation) ver 1.2
[    3.024111] Bluetooth: HIDP socket layer initialized
```

Bootup goes smoothly up until right after loading the touchpad, where it would hang:

```
[    7.307114] input: FSPPS/2 Sentelic FingerSensingPad as /devices/platform/i8042/serio2/input/input13
```

After about a minute, the following error would display and the system would resume booting as normal.

```
[   64.440637] Bluetooth: Patch file not found ar3k/AthrBT_0x11020000.dfu
[   64.443594] Bluetooth: Loading patch file failed
[   64.446465] ath3k: probe of 3-4:1.0 failed with error -2
```

And this is the problem that I am still having, except that last night when I was messing around with it it magically started working. I ran an `rfkill list` and there it was, hci0! `hcitool` also showed the device, so I was good to go, I went into `bluetoothctl` and paired my mouse, added a udev rule to get everything running at boot, the works. I rebooted my computer a couple times and it worked like a charm, it didn't hang at boot, so I guess it got the firmware to load.

This morning I woke up and my laptop had unplugged and the battery had died, I booted back up, and sure enough, hang at the boot screen and the same error as before (or at least a similar one, I don't remember if I was missing the same firmware file originally or if something else was causing the module not to load). hci0 is suddenly nowhere to be found again.

I don't know if it was the fact that the computer completely shut down (I had only been rebooting it) that caused the physical device to deactivate, but I don't see a physical switch anywhere on my computer (Sager NP8298 built on Clevo P177SM-A) for Bluetooth, no keyboard toggle either.

Any ideas on how to get the computer to see the device? Everything worked beautifully when it was working.

Edit: Some `ls` output

```
[vinny@gentoo ~]$ ls -l /lib/firmware | grep ar3k
drwxr-xr-x 7 root root    4096 Sep 18 15:00 ar3k
[vinny@gentoo ~]$ ls -l /lib/firmware | grep ath3k
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  246804 Sep 18 14:16 ath3k-1.fw
[vinny@gentoo ~]$ cd /lib/firmware/ar3k && ls
1020200    AthrBT_0x01020001.dfu  AthrBT_0x41020000.dfu    ramps_0x01020201_40.dfu
1020201    AthrBT_0x01020200.dfu  ramps_0x01020001_26.dfu  ramps_0x11020000_40.dfu
30000      AthrBT_0x01020201.dfu  ramps_0x01020200_26.dfu  ramps_0x31010000_40.dfu
30101      AthrBT_0x11020000.dfu  ramps_0x01020200_40.dfu  ramps_0x41020000_40.dfu
30101coex  AthrBT_0x31010000.dfu  ramps_0x01020201_26.dfu
```

Comment: Have you emerged the firmware needed?

Comment: Yeah, it's in linux-firmware. ath3k-1.fw is in /lib/firmware.

Comment: Please `ls -l /lib/firmware | grep ar3k`

Comment: OP edited with output.

Comment: Also, it's working again! For now, at least. I suspect if I do a hard reboot it won't though, is there any info that you want while it's working before I try rebooting?

Comment: `cd /lib/firmware/ar3k && ls`  i want to see if you have any firmware files in ar3k as thats why dmesg is complaining.

Comment: Done and edited.

Comment: Sure enough  Go to this [Github Fork](https://github.com/cernekee/linux-firmware/blob/master/ar3k/AthrBT_0x11020000.dfu), and click View Raw.  Put the downloaded file in the /lib/firmware/ar3k directory, reboot and replace your dmesg in the post. While you do that ill investigate the touchpad issue.

Comment: Also I did find ar3k/AthrBT_0x11020000.dfu somewhere and downloaded it as it wasn't in there and it was the file that dmesg was bitching about, but it didn't change the output at all.

Comment: Comment Edited I hit Enter Sorry.  Save the Github Fork in your Bookmarks... This is one reason I hate Wireless on Linux :(

Comment: Well, I replaced the file, rebooted and it's still working, hopefully it stays that way. I'd be more confident if it had fixed the problem when it wasn't working at all, but I'm still curious as to what has been causing hci0 to go in and out. Oh, and the touchpad is fine, that just happened to be the last line of the dbus output before BT got stuck. Just there to illustrate how long it would hang at boot.

Comment: See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24174547/how-to-solve-cant-init-device-hci0-error) as a start.

Comment: Blech, it's broken again. The only correlation that I see between the times that I've had it working and then stop working is that the battery died both times overnight, when I booted up, back to freezing at boot and then the same error message as before. Reinstalled the firmware file, still the same problem. Should I be building ath3k as a module?

Comment: Build all the ath modules and remove them one at a time.  When it stops working add it back